# xpolog count syntax

Tags: xpolog, xpolog-search

I have a website with application pool "accounts.services"

I want to use xpolog to group all logs by their title

and order them by their count

I have tried:

```
(Computer = VM2014.conduit.local ) in app.accountsservices | count | group by Source | order by count des
```

but go syntax error 
what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Computer contains VM2014 in app.accountsservices | count | group by source | order by count desc
```